# has many through delete link Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a big problem !

i have three models, School,Secretaries and Schools_Secretary.
School_secretary make a join model, and works fine.. but after add a record, i cant delete the same. ;(
Someone can help me ?

I dont want delete depent destroy, because School and Secretary never deleted, i want delete only join model record on table schools_secretaries

**Secretary.rb**

```
      class Secretary < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 has_many :schools_secretaries
  has_many :schools, :through => :schools_secretaries,:uniq => true

end
```

**School.rb**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :schools_secretaries
    has_many :secretaries, :through => :schools_secretaries,:uniq => true

end
```

**schools_secretary.rb**

```
class SchoolsSecretary < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :secretary
    belongs_to :school
end
```

**routes.rb** to acess localhost/schools/1/secretaries/1

```
resources :schools  do
 resources :schools_secretaries
 resources :secretaries
 devise_for :secretaries, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

end

**show.html.erb .. Action new work fine, i can insert register in table**

```
    <%= form_for [@school,SchoolsSecretary.new], :method => :post,:remote => true do  %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :school_id, @school.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :secretary_id, @secretary.id %> 
  <%= submit_tag 'Adicionar' %>
<% end %>
```

**schools_secretaries_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    @secretary = Secretary.find(params[:secretary_id])

    schools_secretary_params = { :school_id => @school.id, :secretary_id => @secretary.id }

    @schools_secretary = SchoolsSecretary.new(schools_secretary_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @schools_secretary.save
        format.html { redirect_to @schools_secretary, notice: 'Schools secretary was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @schools_secretary }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @schools_secretary.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the join table record, lets assume that you have @school and @secretary. Now try the following code.

```
@school.secretaries.delete(@secretary)
```

Comment: Thx Sir,
I found a solution loking http://asciicasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association